# JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript button that is meant to set `SAPReleased__c` = "True" whenever it is pushed.  Now this should only work when `Approved__c` is True.  This is my current code which isn't working.. Any thoughts?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")} 
//Query the record from the DB.
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select Name,Approved__c,SAPReleased__c,Sample_Fullfillment_Channel__c from Sampling__c where Id=\'{!Sampling__c.Id}\'");
var records = result.getArray("records");
//Since we are dealing with one record per button we can just take the 1st val from 
//the records array.
var Sampling = records[0];
if(Sampling.Approved__c){
  Sampling.SAPReleased__c = 'TRUE'; 
  Sampling.Sample_Fullfillment_Channel__c = 'SAP'; 
}
else{
  alert('Sample must be approved before it can be booked.');
}

result = sforce.connection.update([Sampling]);
window.location.reload();
```

> So update to my code I changed it from "True" to 1, in which it appears that it is getting inside of my Loop, now I just need to figure out how to set SAPReleased__c == True.  It isn't getting updated how I have it now.

It is running but it isn't setting my check box to "True" Is this right?

```
Sampling.SAPReleased__c = true;
```

Comment: Are you trying to create new object and then update the newly created record or trying to update an existing record?

Comment: I'm trying to update the existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this, if you do not want to deal with Javascript's case sensitivity you can go down Visual force page route 
Create button and set content source as Visual force.

Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Sampling__c" extensions="SAP_Controller" action="{!set_sap_val}">

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class SAP_Controller{
public Account acct;

public SAP_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();

}

public PageReference set_sap_val{
   if(acct.Approved__c == "Approved"){
      //do whatever.
   }
}

}
```

Try this :

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")} 
    //Query the record from the DB.
    var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Name,Approved__c,Sample_Fullfillment_Channel__c,Sample_Fullfillment_Channel__c from Sampling__c where Id=\'{!Sampling__c.Id}\'");
    var records = result.getArray("records");
   //Since we are dealing with one record per button we can just take the 1st val from 
   //the records array.
    var sampling = records[0];
    if(sampling.Approved__c){
      //for boolean(checkbox) use true without ''. anything inside '' is a string.
      sampling.SAPReleased__c = true; 
      sampling.Sample_Fullfillment_Channel__c = 'SAP'; 
    }
    else{
      alert('Sample must be approved before it can be booked.');
    }

result = sforce.connection.update([sampling]);
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Sorry I should of said Approved__c and SAPReleased__c is a check box, I will give this a try though

Comment: @EricSSH I just modified his code to change if(sampling.Approved__c == "Approved"){ to if(sampling.Approved__c){ but I don't know if it's come through yet

Comment: @NathanWilliams I was updating the answer :/, I updated the edits on my answer :).

Comment: So it's running, but I don't think it isn't setting SAPReleased__c, is this right?  Sampling.SAPReleased__c = 'TRUE';  It is a checkbox, I have tried 1, and '1'

Comment: @Rao it comes back as as error "True is not defined" I tried true, also doesn't work.

Comment: @EricSSH are you sure sampling.SAPReleased__c = true; is not working, I tried in my org and the checkbox is working fine. Also once you save the button refresh the record you are working on else the button code will still reference to the old version sometimes

Comment: use true and not TRUE. JS is case sensitive, and refresh the record before hitting the button once the button code is updated.

Comment: SAPReleased isn't showing checked on my Sampling form after I Book it.. Should I be expecting it to?

Comment: is the approved__C a text box or check box if it is a checkbox and approved__C  value is checked the SAPReleaased should be checked too

Comment: approved__C is a check box.. Something else must be going on in the background I will have to look into, Thanks for your help

Comment: get on chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4337/salesforce

Comment: I don't have 20 rep on the network to chat

Comment: @EricSSH are you logged in you have more than 190 repuatation

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to link my accounts so I can chat..

Comment: @Rao I'm the chat now if you are available